# What is StringIndexer , VectorIndexer, and how to use them?

Tags: apache-spark, dataset, apache-spark-sql

```
Dataset<Row> dataFrame = ... ;   
StringIndexerModel labelIndexer = new StringIndexer()
               .setInputCol("label")
               .setOutputCol("indexedLabel")
               .fit(dataFrame);

 VectorIndexerModel featureIndexer = new VectorIndexer()
               .setInputCol("s")
               .setOutputCol("indexedFeatures")
               .setMaxCategories(4)
               .fit(dataFrame);
IndexToString labelConverter = new IndexToString()
               .setInputCol("prediction")
               .setOutputCol("predictedLabel")
               .setLabels(labelIndexer.labels());
```

What is StringIndexer, VectorIndexer, IndexToString and what is the difference between them? How and When should I use them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know only about those two:

**StringIndexer and VectorIndexer**

StringIndexer:

- converts a single column to an index column (similar to a factor column in R)

VectorIndexer:

- is used to index categorical predictors in a featuresCol column. Remember that featuresCol is a single column consisting of vectors (refer to featuresCol and labelCol). Each row is a vector which contains values from each predictors.
- if you have string type predictors, you will first need to use index those columns with StringIndexer. featuresCol contains vectors, and vectors does not contain string values.

Take a look here for example: https://mingchen0919.github.io/learning-apache-spark/StringIndexer-and-VectorIndexer.html

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: I found the page was moved to https://github.com/MingChen0919/learning-apache-spark - a very good resource!

Comment: @Amit Haim .Could you please explain the meaning of Vector Indexer in lay mans terms. Iam finding it bit difficult to understand the use case of Vector indexer

Comment: @ColinG Please help

Comment: Do you know when you would use one vs the other?

Answer (score 16):

String Indexer - Use it if you want the Machine Learning algorithm to identify column as categorical variable or if want to convert the textual data to numeric data keeping the categorical context.

e,g converting days(Monday, Tuesday...) to numeric representation.

Vector Indexer- use this if we do not know the types of data incoming. so we leave the logic of differentiating between categorical and non categorical data to the algorithm using Vector Indexer.

e,g - Data coming from 3rd Party API, where data is hidden and  is ingested directly to the training model.

Indexer to string- just opposite of String indexer, use this if the final output column was indexed using String Indexer and now we want to convert back its  numeric representation to textual so that result can be understood better.